# How to use Mathematica to simplify this kind of trig sum?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, trigonometry

$$
S=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\sin\left(\frac{(2+4k)\pi}{23}\right)
=\sum_{k=0}^{10}e^\left(i\frac{(2+4k)\pi}{23}\right)
=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{23}}\sum_{k=0}^{10}e^{i\frac{4k\pi}{23}}
=e^{iu}\sum_{k=0}^{10}\left(e^{2iu}\right)^k
$$

For example, I did this by hand, and got an answer as $\frac{1}{2} \tan\left( \frac{\pi}{23} \right)$

But how do I use Mathematica to check?

```
Sum[Sin[Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, 10}]
Sum[Sin[Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, 10}] - Tan[Pi/23]/2 // Simplify
```

I have tried some functions like `Simplify,TrigFactor,TrigToExp`. But I am not sure how to **guide** Mathematica to the final answer.

And similarly, how do I simplify

```
Sum[Sin[(-1)^k*Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, 10}]
```

which I got as $-\frac{1}{2} \tan\left( \frac{2\pi}{23} \right)$.

Comment: (Sum[Sin[Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, 10}] - Tan[Pi/23]/2 )// FullSimplify produces 0 in version 12.0.

Comment: @user64494 I think what he want is , how to get $\frac{1}{2} \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{23}\right)$ by mma. `(Sum[Sin[Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, 10}] - Tan[Pi/23]/2 )// FullSimplify` is for check the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is:

```
Sum[Sin[Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, n}] /. n -> 10 // Simplify

(* 1/2 Tan[\[Pi]/23] *)
```

Comment: The second sum confuses Mathematica in its original form and has to be tweaked a little: `Sum[(-1)^k*Sin[Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, n}] /. n -> 10`

Comment: That's just so weird!! Why wouldn't `Sum[Sin[Pi/23*(2 + 4*k)], {k, 0, 10}]//Simplify` work straight away.....

Comment: @CasperYC. I don't really know, maybe because the algorithm is written in this way,can't find simpler form. Using `Maple` also can't .

Comment: The reason is probably that simplifying such expressions requires guessing the pattern, finding the formula for x_i and then doing the sum the usual way, guessing the pattern being the hardest part of the problem. This would greatly slow down the Simplify function.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk HAHA. That's fine. I gave up `Maple` ten years ago ...